# My plugin's filters and actions don't run everywhere

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin, and I want to do actions on every single page. However, it seems like my plugin will only work if I visiting a page that is using a part of it, for example, a shortcode. On every other pages, it doesn't do anything. How can I tell Wordpress to run my plugin's hooks even if it's not used on that specific page?

I tested it with this code. If I open a page that is using a shortcode registered by my plugin, "HUH?" will appear on the very top of the page.On every other pages, there's nothing...

```
add_action('init', 'myplugin_init');
function myplugin_init() {
    echo 'HUH?';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the "HUH?" message is visible on the login page, and all of the admin pages. I googled a lot and found this article on the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active . As it turned out, I needed to add a line to my theme's functions.php, because plugins aren't loaded by default on the front-end. So here is the solution, add this line to your functions.php:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code is placed as child of a conditional code. For example something like following:

```
if($condition == true)
{
    add_action('init', 'function_to_call');
}
```

For debugging place the code in your main plugin file and see the results.
I hope it works.

Comment: I placed this code in my main file, without any wrapper condition, and it doesn't work unless the viewed page has a direct call to one of my plugins functions/shortcodes...

Comment: Now my main file's first few lines look like this: https://s12.postimg.org/yofefy4u5/whatthe.png